# What is the scope of finalizer thread - per application domain or per process?

Tags: .net, multithreading, process, appdomain, finalizer

Based on all my reading there should be one GC thread to invoke all finalizers. Now, the question is what is the scope of this "one" thread - per process or per application domain, as the whole intention of domains is to separate and make "independent" different applications in one process space.

I read [here](http://dn.codegear.com/article/29365#MoreFinalizerIssues):

> If an unhandled exception occurs in a
>   finalizer the CLR's executing thread
>   will swallow the exception, treat the
>   finalizer as if it completed normally,
>   remove it from the freachable queue
>   and move onto the next entry.
>
> More serious though, is what happens
>   if your finalizer doesn't exit for
>   some reason, for example it blocks,
>   waiting for a condition that never
>   occurs. **In this case the finalizer
>   thread will be hung, so no more
>   finalizable objects will be garbage
>   collected.** You should be very much
>   aware of this situation and stick to
>   writing the simplest code to free your
>   unmanaged resources in finalizers.
>
> Another consideration is what happens
>   during application shutdown. When the
>   program shuts, the garbage collector
>   will endeavour to call the finalizers
>   of all finalizable objects, but with
>   certain limitations:
>
> - Finalizable objects are not promoted
>     to higher heap generations during
>     shutdown.
> - Any individual finalizer will have a
>     maximum of 2 seconds to execute; if it
>     takes longer it will be killed off.
> - There is a maximum of 40 seconds for
>     all finalizers to be executed; if any
>     finalizers are still executing, or
>     pending at this point the whole
>     process is abruptly killed off.

Too many posts (and even official documentation) misuse of the terms "application", "process" and "application domain" - most of them even assuming that they are equal, because usually applications are run in a single application domain in a single process. This misuse makes all of these docs hard to read, and not even useful.

So, my question assumes more than one applications, each run in a separate application domain in a single process.

Does all these application share the same GC and finalizer threads? Does the problem described in the article above (hang finalizer thread) will affect all applications in that process? If yes - is there a workaround (besides to not use bad applications), like somehow to discover the finalizer thread and send it Thread.Abort?

All above is because I hit similar problem. My application runs in a separate application domain as addin to third party software (Outlook). Because of various reasons I need to call GC.Collect and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers to fully release COM references (the usual interop routines are not enough for Office/Outlook), when a particular other third party addin is running, my GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers hangs forever, so I suspect that there is a "bad" finalizer in that third party adding. I have no control over replacing/removing that adding (client's requirement), so I have to figure out on my own how to make them co-exist.

Comment: +1 for a clear and detailed question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like it is indeed just one thread per CLR instance within the process - at the moment, anyway. Here's some code to show that:

Test.cs:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain.CreateDomain("First")
                 .ExecuteAssembly("ShowFinalizerThread.exe");
        AppDomain.CreateDomain("Second")
                 .ExecuteAssembly("ShowFinalizerThread.exe");
    }
}
```

ShowFinalizerThread.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class ShowFinalizerThread
{
    static Random rng = new Random();

    ~ShowFinalizerThread()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread/domain: {0}/{1}",
                          Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        if (rng.Next(10) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hanging!");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        new Thread(LoopForever).Start();
    }

    static void LoopForever()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            new ShowFinalizerThread();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        };
    }
}
```

Compile each as a console app, then run test.exe (from the command line is easiest, IMO). You'll see that one app domain's finalizer blocks another.

In the future I wouldn't be surprised to see one finalizer thread per *core* rather than per AppDomain - but it sounds like you'll still have problems :(

You have my deepest sympathy (though not a solution) - once I tracked down a deadlock in an Oracle Blob. We were able to fix that by disposing of it properly, but I know not everything works that nicely - and it was a real pain even finding that one!

Comment: I believe it's one thread per CLR instance.  Starting with 2.0 and silverlight you can now have more than one CLR per process.

Comment: @JaredPar - you're right on it...[CLR Inside Out: In-Process Side-by-Side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819091.aspx)

Comment: @JonSkeet  , regarding _one finalizer thread per core_ , now in 2012 , did they do it ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Don't know, I'm afraid.